# How to pass an argument for glob in fzf.vim Rg to support searching in specific files?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, plugin-fzf, fzf, ripgrep

I am using [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) plugin with [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/).

Fzf comes with the command `:RG` and `:Rg`right out of the box that lets me to search for keywords in files.

However, often I need to search for keywords in *specific files*. For example: instead of looking for `foo` anywhere in the Project, I may need to search for `foo` only in `.js` files.

I am able to *hardcode* the file type into the `:Rg` command. The following code allows me to run `:Rg` and it will search for keywords only in `.js` files

```
function! RgRunner()
  return 'rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case -g "*.{js}" '
endfunction

command! -bang -nargs=* Rg
  \ call fzf#vim#grep(RgRunner().shellescape(<q-args>), 1, fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': '--delimiter : --nth 4..'}), <bang>0)
```

So now when I run `:Rg`, it searches only in JS files.

[image: fzf js files]

And if I change it from `*.{js}` to  `*.{rb}` ( `return 'rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case -g "*.{rb}" '`), `:Rg` now searches only in `.rb` files:

[image: fzf rb files]

The problem is, these are currently hardcoded. I am having trouble writing the Vim script `command` that accepts a user input for the glob pattern. I need it so when I run:

- `:Rg '*.{rb}'` it searches only in Ruby files
- `:Rg '*.{js}'` it searches only in JS files,
- and so on

How can I change the function/command that I have to accept user-input glob arguments?

[image: fzf command passing glob]

*That way, when I run `:Rg '*.{js}'` (or something like that) and fzf.vim lets me to fuzzy-search within the `.js` file constraint?*

Comment: Have you tried using grepprg instead? I can share more details if you’re interested.

Comment: Yeah, I have greppg set: `set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep\ --smart-case`. I can run command like: `:grep -g *.rb foo` to search for "foo" in ruby files. This is my current means of searching for keywords in specific files - but I am trying to get the FZF fuzzy search experience while searching only in specific files.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
function! RgRunner(...)
  let command = 'rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case '
  if a:0 >= 1
    let command = command . '-g ' . a:1 . ' '
  endif
  return command
endfunction

command! -bang -nargs=* Rg
  \ call fzf#vim#grep(RgRunner(<f-args>).shellescape(""), 1, fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': '--delimiter : --nth 4..'}), <bang>0)
```

The `RgRunner` function takes now a variable number of arguments that are passed through `<f-args>`.

`a:0` is the count of arguments passed.

`a:1` is the first argument

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply - It still doesn't work. When I tried to run `:Rg *.js`, it returns: `[Command failed: rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case -g *.js '*.js']`. Vim thinks that the glob argument and the keyword is the same. We just need to figure out a way to separate the arguments. There are basically 2 arguments: The one that's called first with `:Rg ARG1`, and the second one that's called later after Rg runs (the keyword).
`RgRunner` is a good start though. Maybe I can pick it up from there..

Comment: It is unclear to me how you want to make the distinction between the file pattern and the keyword you want to search. If you want always to search the current word we can only use the parameter for the file pattern (I have modified the solution accordingly :-) ).

Comment: Did you tried to use the the `-g *.js` flag in the normal Fzf?

Comment: No, I don't think it'll work. The `-g` (glob) option is Ripgrep's (https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#manual-filtering-globs). Fzf.vim has built-in integration with Ripgrep (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#commands, under `:Rg`), but I don't think the integrated `:Rg` or `:RG` command accepts globbing. https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/master/plugin/fzf.vim#L57